# Click on element is present not working : error (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'presence_of_element_located')

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I want to click on an element when is present but I have this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute presence_of_element_located'
```

This is my code in Pycharm:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/md-content/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[1]/div/section[1]/h2/button[1]'))
    element.click()
finally:
    self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: Evidently `EC` is a String. If that's not what you're expecting, you'll need to do some debugging. You haven't provided enough information for us to be able to help you though.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check whether you import *Expected Conditions* as

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

and then didn't overwrite `EC` variable, e.g.

```
EC = "//div"
```

... or something

Comment: Now it give me this error (unexpected argument) for this
"/html/body/div[1]/section/md-content/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[1]/div/section[1]/h2/button[1]"

Comment: @FlutterLover , try to add one more parenthesis pair: `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/section/md-content/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/md-content/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[1]/div/section[1]/h2/button[1]'))`

Comment: i have this error for click :
../../../../../../../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:80: in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
../../../../../../../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:633: in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
../../../../../../../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: @FlutterLover , I see only part of exception and it gives me no useful information at all((

Comment: Finaly i have found a solution 
element = self.driver.find_element_by_id('adminCreateConsultation')
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)